# Align Image correctly using minipages

Tags: graphics, article

I'm currently trying to make a poster style - thingy in latex. I want to have text, an image next to it, and then text below all of that. Here is my code:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
    \usepackage[]{microtype}
    \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
    \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
        \usepackage{parskip}
    }{% else
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
    \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Final},
    hidelinks,
    pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\title{Colorado River Zeugs}
\author{User 1986}
\date{\today}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    
    
    \subsubsection{Technische Daten}\label{technische-daten}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \tightlist
            \item Ort der Quelle: im Rocky-Mountain-Nationalpark
            \item Mündung des Flusses: Golf von Kalifornien
            \item Länge: 2334~km
            \item Anliegerstaaten
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item Utah
                \item Colorado (State)
                \item Arizona
                \item California
                \item Nevada
                \item Baja California
                \item Sonora
            \end{itemize}
            \item Wichtigste Nebenflüsse
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item little Colorado
                \item Gila
                \item San Juan
            \end{itemize}
            \item Art der Mündungsform (Delta oder x)
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item einfache Mündung
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{colorado.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \tightlist
        \item Wassermenge/Abflussmenge
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \tightlist
            \item
            Die Wassermenge, die der Colorado River transportiert, variiert
            während des Jahres und je nach Wetterbedingungen. Im Durchschnitt
            transportiert der Colorado River jedoch etwa 17,5 Milliarden
            Kubikmeter Wasser pro Jahr. Allerdings in den letzten Jahrzehnten
            ist die Wassermenge aufgrund von Dürren und menschgemachten
            Entnahmen deutlich reduziert worden.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    
\end{document}
```

Despite my precious efforts, it looks like this:
[image: Sad Description]

Does anybody know how to fix this, and make it so that the image fits in with the other stuff?
Here is the image I'm trying to embed: https://b.catgirlsare.sexy/UcvhG3pozrRP.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `\vspace{0pt}` as first line in the minipage. It is an invisible line which will be on the same height as the first line in the other minipage.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{iftex}
\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\else
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
    \usepackage[]{microtype}
    \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
    \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
        \usepackage{parskip}
    }{% else
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
    \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Final},
    hidelinks,
    pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\title{Colorado River Zeugs}
\author{User 1986}
\date{\today}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    
    
    \subsubsection{Technische Daten}\label{technische-daten}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \tightlist
            \item Ort der Quelle: im Rocky-Mountain-Nationalpark
            \item Mündung des Flusses: Golf von Kalifornien
            \item Länge: 2334~km
            \item Anliegerstaaten
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item Utah
                \item Colorado (State)
                \item Arizona
                \item California
                \item Nevada
                \item Baja California
                \item Sonora
            \end{itemize}
            \item Wichtigste Nebenflüsse
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item little Colorado
                \item Gila
                \item San Juan
            \end{itemize}
            \item Art der Mündungsform (Delta oder x)
            
            \begin{itemize}
                \tightlist
                \item einfache Mündung
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/tmp/colorado.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \tightlist
        \item Wassermenge/Abflussmenge
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \tightlist
            \item
            Die Wassermenge, die der Colorado River transportiert, variiert
            während des Jahres und je nach Wetterbedingungen. Im Durchschnitt
            transportiert der Colorado River jedoch etwa 17,5 Milliarden
            Kubikmeter Wasser pro Jahr. Allerdings in den letzten Jahrzehnten
            ist die Wassermenge aufgrund von Dürren und menschgemachten
            Entnahmen deutlich reduziert worden.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]